# How to implement direct search from url bar in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

So I noticed that when on GitHub you can directly search after you press the spacebar after "github.com" the URL bar goes to "search mode" like this (on chrome)
[image]

How can I add the same functionality to my angular project (angular v9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Tab to Search" and is a feature of Chrome/Chromium and other browsers and it is the implementation of the OpenSearch specification.

Enabling this requires a couple of steps:

1. Add `<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="url_of_osdd_file" title="Website Name">` to the page header.
2. Add the following "OSDD" file, linked from the `link` in step 1 (this is the bare minimum set of options):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <ShortName>Search My Site</ShortName>
 <Description>Search My Site</Description>
 <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://my_site/{searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

[Check this](https://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search) for more details.

Keep in mind that, this feature can be added to any website, but it does require that the website itself supports/provides the search capability (chrome or Google by itself won't be doing the search on behalf of the website using this method).